# Help with finding an Open Cover in $\Bbb{E}^2$ with no finite subcovering

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $D = \{(x,y) | x^2 + y^2 < 1\}$, a bounded but not closed, and hence not compact, subset of $\Bbb{E}^2$.

Give an example of an open covering of $D$ with no finite subcovering.

I understand how to do this in $\Bbb{E}^1$ but I can't seem to grasp how to do this beyond knowing that I want to create some infinite union which converges to what is given?

Thank you in advance for the help.

**EDIT:**

In response to the comment. As an example, if I was doing

$C= \{x \in \Bbb{E}^1 | x \ge 1\}$ then an open covering would be

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (1 , n)$

The above should be the set $[1,\infty)$.

Fingers crossed I haven't completely misunderstood!

Comment: How do you do it in $\mathbb{E}^1$? Write it down here, please.

Comment: I added an edit to my original question! Thank you for your response. Hopefully I did it correctly.

Comment: It's a bit unclear to me; I would have thought (consistent with what $\mathbb{E}^2$ is) that $\mathbb{E}^1$ would be $(-1, 1)$. Do you know how to write down an open cover of $(-1,1 )$ that has no finite subcover?

Comment: Yes. Infinite union of $(\frac{1}{n} - 1 , 1 - \frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Right. Now draw a picture of circles with radius $1 - 1/n$ centered at the origin. What can you conclude?

Comment: The radius approaches 1 as n approaches infinity. So is it proper to write,

$\cup_{n=1}^{\infty} (x^2 + y^2 < 1- \frac{1}{n})$

Comment: Yes, that will be a cover of the set (once you rewrite it in set notation). Now you need to argue that it's an open cover and has no finite subcover, but the idea is exactly the same as the one-dimensional version.